# Adding more than 100 markers on map,freezes the whole page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with more than 100 markers.I have done a Ajax request to server and get a xml response which contains the lot of lat,lon values.Looping these values and add each marker on map with label. The ajax request and response are occurred quickly and each markers are added to map quickly.Then the whole page freeze for some time.Then markers are display as large then come to l normal. Why the Google map do like this?

**My Code for ajax request,response and add marker on map :**

```
ajaxRequests[ax]=$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myurl",
        dataType: "xml",
        async:true,
        success: function(xml) {
            if (markersArray) {
                for (i in markersArray) {
                    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }
            routepoints = new Array();

            $(xml).find('value').each(function(){
                var latt=$(this).find('lat').text();
                var lonn=$(this).find('lon').text();
                routepoints[i] = new Array(name,ct,latt,lonn,phone); 
                addMarker(i);
                i=i+1;
            });

            mzoom=map.getZoom();
        }
    });


function addMarker(tt)
{ 
    var icont;
    if(tt==0)
        icont='images/green.png';
    else if(tt==(total_markers-1))
        icont='images/red.png';
    else
        icont='images/purple.png';


    var idm=(tt+1)+") "+routepoints[tt][1];
    var clocation= new google.maps.LatLng(routepoints[tt][2],routepoints[tt][3]);
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: clocation,
            map: map,
            labelContent: idm,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 5),
            labelClass: "labels",
            icon: icont
            });
    if(tt==0 || (tt+1)==total_markers)
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        else
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
    markersArray.push(marker);
    map.panTo(clocation);
}
```

Comment: this is because you are accessing the DOM everytime you are adding a marker, please look at the google maps API and find a way to freeze updates add all items to the array and then update all at once this will solve your issue.  This is the same issue as adding 1000's of items to a dropdown at once.

Comment: yes I can add the lat,lon values in an array and update  to  map at once. But i need to display corresponding time of each marker as a label on each marker. So google api support any option to add label on each marker?

Comment: you can't just make the markers add them to the array and then bind the map to the array?

Comment: can i add lat,lon and also time in array and bound to the map?

Comment: You should consider to remove the animation

Answer (score 0):

I used Google maps utility library Clusterer API. The markers are displayed on map based on zoom level.Now it solves my whole page hanging issue.

The following links will be helper to use Clusterer API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html